# Unable to run shell script inside VI/VIM

Tags: command-line, scripts, vim

I am trying to run a shell-script say test from vim

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo good morning
```

Now when I am using `:!%`
I am getting a pop like

```
shell returned 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

instead of `good morning`.

Someone please tell me what am I doing wrong. Do I have to change the path,if so how to do it. Running it from my home folder

Comment: Do you also get a message saying "Permission denied"?

Comment: If so, as azzid told you, you will have to make the script executable.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

That will only work if the script file's permissions have the executable bit set. You can do this through Vim

```
:! chmod +x %
:! ./%
```

Or you could just run it through its interpreter manually:

```
:! bash %
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
:!./%
```

I use bash, so my error codes are different, but the path gets a bit of when you run % directly.

Also, you might need to run `:!chmod u+x ./%` before to make the script executable.